# homebrew mysql os lion - CMake Error at cmake/do_abi_check.cmake:78

Tags: mysql, cmake, osx-lion, homebrew

I recently upgraded from snow leopard to lion. I've got the latest version of Homebrew running (e.g. I ran 'brew update'). I'm trying to install mysql but I get the error below.

Googling for how to fix this has turned up nothing...

```
$ brew install mysql
==> Downloading http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.5/mysql-5.5.19.tar.gz
File already downloaded in /Users/evan/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Patching
patching file scripts/mysqld_safe.sh
patching file scripts/mysql_config.sh
==> cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.19 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var/mysql -DINSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/local/C
==> make
Scanning dependencies of target INFO_BIN
Scanning dependencies of target INFO_SRC
Scanning dependencies of target abi_check
[  0%] Built target INFO_SRC
Scanning dependencies of target readline
1,240d0

[ ---- I've truncated the source dump ---- ]

CMake Error at cmake/do_abi_check.cmake:78 (MESSAGE):
  ABI check found difference between
  /tmp/homebrew-mysql-5.5.19-mGpc/mysql-5.5.19/include/mysql/plugin_audit.h.pp
  and /tmp/homebrew-mysql-5.5.19-mGpc/mysql-5.5.19/abi_check.out


Scanning dependencies of target gen_lex_hash
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/abi_check] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/abi_check.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  1%] [  2%] [  2%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/readline.c.o
Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/funmap.c.o
Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/gen_lex_hash.dir/gen_lex_hash.cc.o
[  2%] Built target INFO_BIN
[  2%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/keymaps.c.o
[  2%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/vi_mode.c.o
[  2%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/parens.c.o
[  2%] [  3%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/rltty.c.o
Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/complete.c.o
Linking CXX executable gen_lex_hash
[  3%] Built target gen_lex_hash
[  3%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/bind.c.o
[  3%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/isearch.c.o
[  3%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/display.c.o
[  3%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/signals.c.o
[  3%] [  4%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/kill.c.o
Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/util.c.o
[  4%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/undo.c.o
[  4%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/macro.c.o
[  4%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/input.c.o
[  4%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/callback.c.o
[  4%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/terminal.c.o
[  4%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/xmalloc.c.o
[  5%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/history.c.o
[  5%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/histsearch.c.o
[  5%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/histexpand.c.o
[  5%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/histfile.c.o
[  5%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/nls.c.o
[  5%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/search.c.o
[  6%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/shell.c.o
[  6%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/tilde.c.o
[  6%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/misc.c.o
[  6%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/text.c.o
[  6%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/mbutil.c.o
[  6%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/compat.c.o
[  7%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/savestring.c.o
Linking C static library libreadline.a
[  7%] Built target readline
make: *** [all] Error 2
==> Exit Status: 2
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mysql.rb#L75
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8.1
HEAD: 0e8ea8aae9dadda53d0dc0cf680d383981770be9
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
Hardware: quad-core 64-bit arrandale
OS X: 10.7.3
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Xcode: 3.2.6
GCC-4.0: N/A
GCC-4.2: N/A
LLVM: build 2336
Clang: 3.1 build 318
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11: /usr/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-249
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Which Perl:   /usr/bin/perl
Which Python: /usr/bin/python
Which Ruby:   /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/xcrun gcc-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

CXX: /usr/bin/xcrun g++-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2

LD: /usr/bin/xcrun gcc-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/include
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib
MAKEFLAGS: -j4

Error: Failed executing: make
```

**UPDATE**

I think thinks may be related to conflicting versions of XCode. I've installed the latest version fo XCode, but homebrew still thinks I have the old version installed

```
Warning: You have Xcode-3.2.6, which is outdated.
Please install Xcode 4.3.
```

Attempting a fix....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I solved this bad boy. I'll leave this up to help anyone else who might have the same problem.

Steps to solve

1. run "brew doctor" - begin fixing issues
2. apparently I had several versions of XCode installed and it was using the old, 3.2 version
3. Uninstalled the old XCode using **only do this in the correct directory which could be different from mine**

   sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools
4. restart and run 'brew doctor' again
5. Use the following command to assign the right XCode version (this may be different depending on your install)

   sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app

And voila! I was able to use homebrew to install mysql

Comment: It's great that you've fixed your problem and documented it well, but remember to come back in a couple of days to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This failed for me. What worked was:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

which was suggested by brew doctor.